# How to render a value as selected in a dropdown with static values

Tags: html

Here is  my code snippet

## foreach( $issueCheckPointConfig in $issueCheckPointConfiguration )

```
<tr class="elements-row grey-rows-on-edit " data-row_id="vfvfs5ks2" id="$i">
    <td headers="coyxsnmhe" class=""><div>$issueCheckPointConfig.getCheckPoint()</div></td>
    <td headers="bgd3200zb" class="">
      <div>
        <select name="status" id="status" >
            <option value="Select">Select</option>  
            <option selected>$issueCheckPointConfig.getStatus()</option>                
            <option value="YES" >YES</option> 
            <option value="NO" >NO</option> 
            <option value="NA" >NA</option> 
        </select>
     </div>
   </td>
```

## end

From the above code dropdown is having the save data as selected once the page is loaded.**But the problem here is , if the saved data is "YES", then after loading the page i can see 2 YES values.**
Same is case with any values, if "NO" is selected and saved then "NO" appears twice.

Please suggest me a way to keep the saved value as selected by avoiding the duplicates.

Comment: You can hide the `option` if saved data `matched the value of that option`.

Comment: how can that be archived...can you plz share the code snippet